# Setting the ASP.NET ConnectionString to a specific domain user

Tags: asp.net, web-config, connection-string

We have a windows account in the SQL Server 2008 called drwho for example
and a password. In the connection string we disabled integrated security and added User Id and password values.

```
User Id=THEDOMAIN\drwho;Password=......
```

However ASP.NET keeps thinking we are using SQL server authentication.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot connect to SQL server using a domain user/pass. If you wish to connect as a domain user, you need to specify integrated security and run your ASP.NET process as that user.
See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998297.aspx) at Microsoft for more information.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to use [impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(VS.71).aspx) to do this. As far as I'm aware you can't pass domain usernames/passwords in connection strings only a trusted connection, .e.g.

```
<identity impersonate="true"
          userName="domain\user" 
          password="password" />
```

Comment: But remember this modifies the whole process to run as this user, so you may bump into resource permissions when doing this. Also, have a look at `CryptProtectData` to help encrypt the password stored in the config file. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72wdk8cc.aspx

Answer (score -1):

the best place to check the validity of your connections strings is [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

I suspect that you have not quite got the format correct.

Answer (score -1):

Have you had a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/?  Always a good resource if you're having connection problems.